# Cant get data from Foursquare API using rest kit

Tags: objective-c, restkit, foursquare

I have used this tutuorial: [Tutorial link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/58682/introduction-restkit-tutorial#comments)

To use in my xcode project. I have followed it and everything works, but i just can not get contact information for venues. My app collects information on venues based on latitude and longitude for adresses.

```
    RKObjectMapping *contactMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Contact class]];
[statsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"phone": @"phon_e", @"formattedPhone": @"form_p", @"twitter": @"twit_ter"}];

[venueMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"contact" toKeyPath:@"contact" withMapping:contactMapping]];
```

this is the code i use to gather gather data from foursquares API, i can get location, and stats info (like the tutorial). and i have done preceisely the same on getting contact information like i did with "stats".

1. create a data model Contact class:
2. Make a property of the Contact class in Venue.h (my data model class) (same in the tutorial)
3. use the above code

the app just crashes with this error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key contact.'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: So your mapping doesn't match your model. Show the model class and the JSON.

Comment: (@)property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *phon_e;                          (@)property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *form_p;
(@)property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *twit_ter;

Comment: `son`? I haven't read the article, your questions should show all pertinent details. What about `contact` ?

Comment: this is some of the json: venues: [
{
id: "4dc91970b0fbf26798c2c42c"
name: "Hackney Picturehouse"
contact: {
phone: "+448719025734"
formattedPhone: "+44 871 902 5734"
twitter: "hackneyph"
}
location: {
address: "270 Mare St"
lat: 51.54478699184793
lng: -0.055301675852133136
distance: 6987
postalCode: "E8 1HE"
cc: "GB"
city: "Hackney"
state: "Greater London"
country: "Storbritannien"
formattedAddress: [
"270 Mare St"
"Hackney"
"Greater London"
"E8 1HE"
"Storbritannien"
]
}

Comment: Anyone ?, i dont understand why contact info doesnt map

Comment: Where is `contact` in your model?

Comment: contact is in another class, where i make a property of class Contact.

Comment: ``@class Location;
@class Stats;
@class Contact;




@interface Venue : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Location *location;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Stats *stats;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Contact *contact;``

Comment: Please edit the question to add this info, it isn't readable in comments... Add the model class definitions, the JSON sample and the full mappings.